# customize-cra - Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-app-rewired, customize-cra

I am using react-app-rewired to configure my CRA project as I was having issues with 2 co-existing versions of React which I'm sure is a very common use-case for `react-app-rewired/customize-cra`.

Everything has been fine until I required installing `react-native-calendars` as a dependency.
As you can see in my `addBabelPlugins` config; I have needed to install `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` to transpile the libraries' components... I am now however getting an error that complains about JSX in my codebase which I thought would already be handled by CRA in the first place and seeing as we are overwriting/extending CRA with `react-app-rewired` i didn't think I would need to add additional plugins/presets such as `@babel/preset-react` & `@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx`...

can somebody point me in the right direction? I'm hoping this issue is common and I have just searched the issues page poorly.

Thank you

#### Info

```rb
react@17.0.1
react-scripts@3.4.3
customize-cra@1.0.0 
npm@6.14.9
node@14.8.0
```

#### Error

```rb
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
SyntaxError: /Users/.../src/App.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (28:5):

  26 | 
  27 |   return (
> 28 |     <Router>
     |     ^
  29 |       <Switch>

Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

#### config-overrides.js

```js
const {
  override,
  addWebpackAlias,
  babelInclude,
  addBabelPresets,
  addBabelPlugins,
} = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  babelInclude([
    require.resolve('./src'),
    require.resolve('./node_modules/react-native-calendars'),
  ]),
  ...addBabelPresets(
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ),
  ...addBabelPlugins(
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', // <~ needed for react-native-calendars
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx',
  ),
  addWebpackAlias({
    react: require.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
  }),
);
```

Original issue [here](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/issues/279)

Comment: Check my answer below, let me know is it helps.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/issues/521#issuecomment-692653369) fixed my issue.

Hopefully, this helps someone else facing this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Replace jsx config option in `jsconfig.json`/`tsconfig.json` like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
-   "jsx": "react-jsx"
+   "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

I found that [here](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-rewire-alias/blob/master/example/main/tsconfig.json). And more info about jsconfig is [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig):

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i created a jsconfig.json and placed `{ "jsx": "react" }` as it's content but no-dice I'm afraid.

Comment: oh that is wrong, I suppose you have already config, I will fix answer

Comment: No Sorry this isn't working. i think this is not something to do with VSCode but babel.

Comment: Thanks for your help see below for my answer